# skobbler can i cache json data?

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, skmaps

I'm using skobbler and skmaps for an app that download for offline use some regions of the map. I'm using the code i have found in the example of the framework package, in this case

```
MapJSONViewController
MapDownloadViewController
```

I have implemented also the app delegate code, so every time i start the app, it download and parse a json of about 1mb

```
- (void)mapsVersioningManager:(SKMapsVersioningManager *)versioningManager loadedWithMapVersion:(NSString *)currentMapVersion
{
    [[XMLParser sharedInstance] downloadAndParseJSON];
}
```

It's possible to avoid this behaviour? I don't want to download 1mb of json data every app init if not necessary... Maybe i can download and include a physic map json file in my app to have a start version ? Or this "local behaviour" will bring my app to work with an outdated json version very soon? Maybe another behaviour is to maintain a local version with a data and redownload it only once a week for example... It seems at me a common problem, there's someone how achive a convenient behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can include the json file in your app & read it from disk.

In the XMLParser.m replace the code in downloadAndParseJson with:

```
- (void)downloadAndParseJSON
{
    [self parseJSON];

    NSString *libraryFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",libraryFolderPath);
}
```

and parseJSON with:

```
- (void)parseJSON
{
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Maps" ofType:@"json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    SKTMapsObject *skMaps = [SKTMapsObject convertFromJSON:jsonString];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate setSkMapsObject:skMaps];

    self.isParsingFinished = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kParsingFinishedNotificationName object:nil];
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/titoiklg6g7d9rj/SKMapsFrameworkDemoWithCustomMapsJson.zip?dl=0) you can find a modified demo project that reads the Maps.json file from resources (the .json file is included in the resources folder).

Comment: Thank you! it works...but in case of map update? I  can't update a file in main bundle. Maybe is better to set maps.json in document folder and build an environment that download and overwrite the file only for new map version... Can i use the delegation  "- (void)mapsVersioningManager:(SKMapsVersioningManager *)versioningManager detectedNewAvailableMapVersion:(NSString *)latestMapVersion currentMapVersion:(NSString *)currentMapVersion
? Or now with a local maps.json it makes not sense ?

Comment: See the SKMapsVersioningDelegate  callbacks for notifications on newer maps: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec33